# can use javascript in only one html object div or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

guys if is possible to use javascript code in only one div or id in html but this javascript code to not affected another div or id on page i try this method but not working

```js
function deposit() {
  DEPOSIT = true;   
}
function withdraw(){
  DEPOSIT = false; 
  $(".norobots").slideUp();
  loadLeft();
}
$(function(){
  $('div[onload]').trigger('onload');
});
function showConfirm() {
  $("#confirmModal").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="withdraw" onload="withdraw();">

</div>
<div class="col-md-6" id="deposit" onload="deposit();">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course! It's possible to use javascript (jquery in your case) to manipulate only divs that has a certain id.

Jquery has selectors (that has the same syntax as CSS) to select divs based in names, CSS classes and ids. It's up to you create a div and give an id to it. But you need to know that your javascript code is present to your entire page and can affect other divs that have the same id, class or name.